# XamlParseException when using Graph# libraries

Tags: xaml, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk, xamlparseexception, graph-sharp

I'm trying to use the [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) libraries in my **VSPackage** project, but unfortunately there are some obstacles to conquer. Here is what I did:

I copied all the following DLL's to a folder /Libraries in the project root:

- GraphSharp.dll
- GraphSharp.Controls.dll
- QuickGraph.dll
- WPFExtensions.dll

The Build Action of all is 'Content' and the option Copy to Output is set to 'Do not copy'.

I added those references to my project. (Add Reference... -> Browse -> select them from the /Library folder)

After that, I created the following files. You can see that the ViewModel is set to be the DataContext of the UserControl and that it defines a "MethodGraph" to which the UI binds.

**XAML file**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Biocoder.InteractiveExploration.View.ExplorationControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:graphsharp="clr-namespace:GraphSharp.Controls;assembly=GraphSharp.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMethods}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Method" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ReturnType" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReflectionInfo.ReturnType}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Incoming Calls"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Outgoing Calls"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <graphsharp:GraphLayout Graph="{Binding MethodGraph}"/>

</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**Code-behind**

```c#
public partial class ExplorationControl : UserControl
{
    public ExplorationControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set the datacontext
        DataContext = InteractiveExplorationPackage.ExplorationToolViewModel;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```c#
public class ExplorationToolViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IBidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>> _methodGraph;

    public IBidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>> MethodGraph
    {
        get { return _methodGraph; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _methodGraph)
            {
                _methodGraph = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MethodGraph");
            }
        }
    }

    public ExplorationToolViewModel()
    {
        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    private void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        SelectedMethods = new ObservableCollection<Method>();
        CreateGraph();
    }

    private void CreateGraph()
    {
        var g = new BidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>>();

        // add vertices
        string[] vertices = new string[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = i.ToString();
            g.AddVertex(vertices[i]);
        }

        // add edges
        g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[0], vertices[1]));
        g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[1], vertices[2]));
        g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[2], vertices[3]));
        g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[3], vertices[1]));
        g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[1], vertices[4]));

        MethodGraph = g;
    }
}
```

Fortunately, I can compile the whole project but at runtime the following error in the XAML occurs on the  tag (right above the needed  tag):

**Could not load file or assembly 'GraphSharp.Controls, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file.**

But I referenced the assemblies, they are listed in the references list.
What's the problem? Could it be that assemblies have to be referenced another way round than usual when writing a **Visual Studio Package** (plugin)?

*EDIT: I just tried to get it work in another project, so I just set up a normal WPF Application and did all the above. In this solution everything works properly! That's so strange!*

Hope you can help me :-)
Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get everything working now. Thanks for your help anyway!

The problem with VSPackages at runtime is basically that they load third party assemblies from another location on the computer called the **Private Assembly folder**. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies) So all you have to do is to copy the referenced assemblies into this folder (requires admin rights). In order to be able to use the assemblies when developing just add those references to your project as you do normally and the compiler will use them the usual way. The only difference is at runtime since Visual Studio loads those references from the Private Assemblies folder.

More information about this can be found here: [Managed VSPackage File Location Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166380%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use nuget in your project? If so, instead copying the dll-s and references manually you should try run `install-package graphsharp` command.

I think that's some kind of `DLL strong name` problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried that already and it gets the same error. I tried also when not signing my project (such that the referenced assemblies can remain unsigned as well) and the error remains. What is very strange is, that in one of 20 cases it works! The GraphLayout as well as the ZoomControl can be loaded and work properly! I'm driving crazy soon, because I tried pretty much everything I'm able to. Would be very nice if you had some further tips! Thank you so far!

Comment: I tried whether it was a signature (strong name) problem. But it isn't. Either you use the Graph# source code and sign the assemblies yourself or you unsign your own project ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx)).
I solved the problem. Of course I'm now using the most recent version loaded from NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one? http://shfb.codeplex.com/workitem/32819

It says:

> I had such an issue and it is discussed somewhere in the discussions. What you need to do is to open the project properties > Paths and there delete all paths (just leave them empty)

Answer (score 0):

Other solution:

1. Add your library as an Assembly Asset to your .vsixmanifest file:
2. Add this code to your package initialization code.

```cs
protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += LoadFromSameFolder;

    static Assembly? LoadFromSameFolder(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var executingAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(executingAssemblyPath) ?? string.Empty;
        var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, $"{new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name}.dll");

        return File.Exists(assemblyPath)
            ? Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath)
            : null;
    }

    // your code
}
```